# Angular 2/4 and Codeigniter based application

Tags: angular, codeigniter

i currently am looking for some help in combining Angluar 2/4 and Codeigniter 3.1.5 technologies to create a application . I am confused as to how to go about with it and need some guidance . Thanks in advance.

Comment: angular is a client side based framework and CI is serverbased - combining both of them shouldn't be a problem at all ...

Comment: Try to type angular 2 codeigniter in github search form. There are some examples.